# Defining a board size (NxN) from keyboard input in Java?

Tags: java

actually I'm working in a batlleship project. And first I'm trying to make the program print the board. I have a for-loop (that includes another for-loop inside) and it does print the board with the values 10x10 like that:

```
  A B C D E F G H I J 
A - - - - - - - - - - 
B - - - - - - - - - - 
C - - - - - - - - - - 
D - - - - - - - - - - 
E - - - - - - - - - - 
F - - - - - - - - - - 
G - - - - - - - - - - 
H - - - - - - - - - - 
I - - - - - - - - - - 
J - - - - - - - - - -
```

But, I'm trying to figure out how can I make the program to take the values NxN through keyboard inputs, in case that the user want different values.  The min number of rows/columns being 5, the maximum being 26.

Comment: I think Scanner would be the best for your idea: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work...

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.In);
int width = readInt("width", in);
int height = readInt("height", in);
for (int x = 0; x < width; x++){
  for (int y = 0; y < height; y++){
    //...
  }
}
private int readInt(String label, Scanner in){
  System.out.println("Enter board " + label);
  return in.nextInt();
}
```